# Mongoose, MATCH operator doesn't return results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, express, mongoose

The `company` parameter has a valid value to obtain the result, but I get an empty array.

```
company = company.replace('.', '');
company = company.replace('.', '');
company = company.replace('-', '');
company = company.replace('/', '');

try {
    const result = await cteModel.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields': {
            date': {
                $dateFromString': { 'dateString': '$dataEmissao' }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: { 'empresa': company }
    },
    {
        $sort: { date: -1, _id: 1 }
    }]);
    res.status(200).send(result);                    
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(500).json(error);
}
```

Comment: add input data and output data to the question

Comment: The query return the deisered result if I substitute the variable by string, like this :
 {
        $match: { 'empresa': '1111' }
  },

Answer (score 0):

The query return the deisered result if I substitute the variable by string, like this : { $match: { 'empresa': '1111' } },